# Best way to secure a xml/csv file

Tags: wpf, encryption

I have a csv/xml file that would be downloaded from my Winforms application. I need to make sure that the csv/xml file is not accessible to the user. What is the best practice to secure the file? I was thinking of either encrypting the file, or making the file password-protected.
Which is the better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't password protect a plain text file so you can either encrypt contents using 256 [AES algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a part of .NET `System.Security.Cryptography` or create a password protected archive using one of the open source compression libraries (which will internally most likely again use AES 256 for encryption).